# Installing django-avatar onto heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-apps

I'm trying to install Django-Avatar onto heroku.

I tried `django-avatar==2.0a9` in my requirements.txt

but got the error:

> "No distributions matching the version for django-avatar==2.0a9"

I then tried `django-avatar==github.com/jezdez/django-avatar/archive/master.zip` and got the error:

> "No such file or directory:
>   '/app/django-avatar==https:/github.com/jezdez/django-avatar/archive/master.zip"

Any thoughts on how I can get django-avatar installed?

I appreciate the time and expertise.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot directly install some thing on heroku.
create a virtual env and 
install django-avatarin local machine, 
update the requirements file using `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
then push the changes.

**Refer this document https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django**

Comment: I first tried that with django-avatar==2.0a9 in my requirements.txt and got the error "No distributions matching the version for django-avatar==2.0a9" I then tried django-avatar==https://github.com/jezdez/django-avatar/archive/master.zip and got the error: "No such file or directory: '/app/django-avatar==https:/github.com/jezdez/django-avatar/archive/master.zip" Any thoughts on what else I could try?